# How to make this end trimming python script faster?

Tags: python, trim

Any suggestions to make this script run faster? I usually have more than two to ten million lines for this script.

```
while True:
    line=f.readline()
    if not line:break
    linker='CTGTAGGCACCATCAAT'
    line_1=line[:-1]
    for i in range(len(linker)):
        if line_1[-i:]==linker[:i]:
            new_line='>\n'+line_1[:-i]+'\n'
            seq_1.append(new_line_1)
            if seq_2.count(line)==0:
                seq_2.append(line)
            else:pass
        else:pass
```

Comment: For starters, format it properly. It won't make the program run faster, but it will help anyone who could change it to run faster.

Comment: python will take a lot of time. And by a lot I mean seriously too much time. Try CPython. C/Python API. Cython, etc.

Comment: Your script is either incomplete or invalid.

Comment: of course, at the end would be f2.writelines(seq_1) and seq_2 is used for screening through the whole file again to find anything doesn't have linker

Comment: Seems like this question might belong on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Name variables clearer that everyone could understand your algorithm quickly and why `line_1` or `seq_1`

Comment: `seq_1.append(new_line_1)` - There is no `new_line_1` in other part of code. `new_line_1` is `new_line`? please, check typos.

Answer (score 3):

First of all it seems that you are creating lots of string objects in the inner loop. You could try to build list of prefixes first:

```
linker = 'CTGTAGGCACCATCAAT'
prefixes = []
for i in range(len(linker)):
    prefixes.append(linker[:i])
```

Additionally you could use `string`'s method `endswith` instead of creating new object in the condition in the inner loop:

```
while True:
    line=f.readilne()
    if not line:
        break
    for prefix in prefixes:
        if line_1.endswith(prefix):
             new_line='>\n%s\n' % line_1[:-len(prefix)]
             seq_1.append(new_line_1)
             if seq_2.count(line)==0:
                 seq_2.append(line)
```

I am not sure about indexes there (like `len(prefix)`). Also don't know how much faster it could be.

Comment: If you iterate over `enumerate(prefixes)` instead of just over prefixes, as in `for prefix_len,prefix in enumerate(prefixes):` then you'll get the len as the enumeration index `prefix_len` without having to call the len function - any time you can avoid calling a function in Python, you win performance.

Comment: `.endswith` is easy for use but slower than `line_1[-i:]==linker[:i]`

Comment: `seq_2.count` - counts. Do you really need count? Suppose, no. So you should use `line in seq_2'.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what your code is meant to do, but general approach is:

1. Avoid unnecessary operations, conditions etc.
2. Move everything you can out of the loop.
3. Try to do as few levels of loop as possible.
4. Use common Python practices where possible (they are generally more efficient).

But most important: try to simplify and optimize the algorithm, not necessarily the code implementing it.

Judging from the code and applying some of the above rules code may look like this:

```py
seq_2 = set()  # seq_2 is a set now (maybe seq_1 should be also?)
linker = 'CTGTAGGCACCATCAAT'  # assuming same linker for every line
linker_range = range(len(linker))  # result of the above assumption
for line in f:
    line_1=line[:-1]
    for i in linker_range:
        if line_1[-i:] == linker[:i]:
            # deleted new_line_1
            seq_1.append('>\n' + line_1[:-i] + '\n')  # do you need this line?
            seq_2.add(line)  # will ignore if already in set
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably a large part of the problem is the `seq_2.count(line) == 0` test for whether `line` is in `seq_2`. This will walk over each element of `seq_2` and test whether it's equal to `line` -- which will take longer and longer as `seq_2` grows. You should use a set instead, which will give you constant-time tests for whether it's present through hashing. This will throw away the order of `seq_2` -- if you need to keep the order, you could use both a set and a list (test if it's in the set and if not, add to both).

This probably doesn't affect the speed, but it's much nicer to loop `for line in f` instead of your `while True` loop with `line = f.readline()` and the test for when to break. Also, the `else: pass` statements are completely unnecessary and could be removed.

The definition of `linker` should be moved outside the loop, since it doesn't get changed. @uhz's suggestion about pre-building prefixes and using `endswith` are also probably good.

Answer (score 0):

**About twise faster** than all theese variants (at least at python 2.7.2)

```
seq_2 = set()
# Here I use generator. So I escape .append lookup and list resizing
def F(f):
    # local memory
    local_seq_2 = set()
    # lookup escaping
    local_seq_2_add = local_seq_2.add
    # static variables
    linker ='CTGTAGGCACCATCAAT'
    linker_range = range(len(linker))
    for line in f:
        line_1=line[:-1]
        for i in linker_range:
            if line_1[-i:] == linker[:i]:
                local_seq_2_add(line)
                yield '>\n' + line_1[:-i] + '\n'
    # push local memory to the global
    global seq_2
    seq_2 = local_seq_2
# here we consume all data
seq_1 = tuple(F(f))
```

Yes, it's ugly and non-pythonic, but it is the fastest way to do the job.

You can also upgrade this code with `with open('file.name') as f:` inside generator or add some other logic.

Note:
This place `'>\n' + line_1[:-i] + '\n'` - is doubtful. On some machines it is the fastest way to concat strings. On some machines the fastest way is  `'>\n'%s'\n'%line_1[:-i]` or `''.join(('>\n',line_1[:-i],'\n'))` (in version without lookup, of course). I dont know what will be best for you.
It is strange, but new formatter `'{}'.format(..)` on my computer shows the slowest result.